# Java - Login to website and retrieve data using SSL/TLSv1

Tags: java, ssl, web

Its tedious to always check your bank account website for new monthly statements. (They are provided via the web interface as pdf).

So, I want to write a client that logs into [this website](http://www.vrbank-hof.de/) and gets the pdfs for me.

While I understand TCP, HTTP and alike, I am new to SSL and encryption beyond HTTP Basic Authentification.

What is the correct approach and/or how can I get that to work?

Greetings,
Jonas Gröger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to understand how SSL/TLS works. You may use an SSLSocket to encrypt and decrypt data for you:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html

You probably may want to check Apache HTTPClient project instead:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

As it already implements HTTP/HTTPS protocol, including proxy and cookies, etc.

Comment: Although I knew the commonds http client, I somehow thought it would be harder to do the ssl stuff. Thank you!